# SQL Server getting corrupt (Template Data\master.mdf file missing)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I kept getting error on starting sql on one PC

**Your SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (Unable to load SQLBOOT.DLL (HRESULT 0x8007007e)).**

I reinstalled SQLServer 3 times and after a day it came back same issue

After lot of digging i finely got to the core error  in this file

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.ENTIREONESQL\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

And the error i got was (at end of file)

```
     -d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Template Data\master.mdf"
     -l "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Template Data\mastlog.ldf"
2016-12-22 08:03:38.48 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2016-12-22 08:03:38.48 Server      Error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while opening file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Template Data\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.
2016-12-22 08:03:38.48 Server      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
```

I looked into the `/Template Data` folder and i see its empty

So i just made a copy from the DATA folder (where the real master.mdf file is)
into the "Template Data" and it all started to work

Now i'm trying to understand.

1) what is this "Template Data" folder all about? if i already have my database in the DATA folder.
2) how did this file get deleted after a while? i reinstalled SQL and restarted pc many times and after a while i got back same error?

Comment: please paste the entire error log and also what do you mean by this `where the real master.mdf file is`

Comment: DATA/master.mdf is the database file that sql hold the data in, but there is a copy of it in "Template Data" and i want to know its purpose